# Estimating VAR of differences of potentially cointegrated variables

Tags: vector-autoregression, cointegration, differencing

What are the possible issues, if any, of estimating a standard two-dimensional $VAR(p)$ of $I(0)$ variables that are first differences of $I(1)$ variables whose potential cointegrating relationship has not been tested? Also, what hints, if any, might you want to look out for in this $VAR(p)$ estimation that might indicate a possible cointegrating relationship between the $I(1)$ variables?

Comment: I appreciate that you have quickly accepted my answer. However, this way you have indicated your problem has been solved and that "the case is closed". Other users who may otherwise have considered contributing answers to this thread might treat it as such. It may be more beneficial for you to leave my answer unaccepted for a couple of days, hoping that someone else would post another answer to the question, and that that answer may contain some helpful points that I have not included in mine.

Comment: @RichardHardy I see. I'll leave the answer unaccepted for a few days. Thank you for your answer and your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the variables $Y$ are cointegrated, VECM is an appropriate model. A VAR for $\Delta Y$ (first-differences of $Y$) is simply the VECM without the error correction term (ECT). Thus, using a VAR for $\Delta Y$ will produce omitted-variable bias.

There is a special case where the appropriate VECM contains zero autoregressive lags. By omitting the ECT, you would end up with a VAR(0) for $\Delta Y$ which is an intercept-only model. In a way, by omitting the ECT you would be throwing out everything there is aside from the constant.

I cannot remember any indications in the VAR for $\Delta Y$ that would betray the fact that VECM is the appropriate model.